# TypeScript Interface implementation

Tags: javascript, typescript, karma-jasmine

```
interface A {
   ():any;
}
class Mock implements A{
}
```

A mock class has to implement `class A`.
I'm getting errors if I use `():any` inside `class Mock`.How should I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use an anonymus function for this, do it like that:

```
interface A {
    func(): any;
}
class Mock implements A {
    func() {
    }
}
```

Note that Mock also need to implement `func`